# Using .env file to specify server listening port of the Next.js server

Tags: next.js

I've been searching for a method how to set up the server port of the Next.js application.
I found 2 methods:

1. Hardcoding into the **package.json** file:

   {
   "scripts": {
   "dev": "next dev  -p 8012",
   "build": "next build",
   "start": "next start -p 8012",
   }
   }
2. From the command line: `npm run dev -- -p 8012` OR `PORT=8012 npm run dev`

None of these looks fine to me.
The problem with the first approach is that **package.json** is versioned by git. This means that I must use the same port on my local env as is used on production. I may have some other program listening on that port locally. This is inconvenient to me.

The second approach implies that my memory serves me very well. I have to memorize the port I want to use locally as well as on production, staging or any other environemnt. This is not OK too.

Ideally, I would like to have the PORT specified in the `.env` files.
I tried it - doesn't work.

Have anyone come across such an issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next.js doesn't currently support using the `PORT` environment variable inside a `.env` file ([See discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/29464)).

The two options that could work for your use case would be:

1. Exporting `$PORT` in your environment. But it has drawbacks, as pointed out in the linked discussion.

```sh
# In your shell
export PORT=8012
```

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "next start --port ${PORT-3000}",
},
```

2. Creating a [custom start script](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/11408#issuecomment-617034254) to read the port from your `.env` file.

```js
//server.js
const cli = require('next/dist/cli/next-start');
cli.nextStart(['-p', process.env.PORT || 3000]);
```

```json
//package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can read the `PORT` environment variable from the `.env` file with the following start script:

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "start": "[ -e .env ] && set -a && . ./.env; next start",
},
```

Using the `set -a` will export the sourced environment variables, and Next.JS start script will start the server in the port defined in `PORT` environment variable. If `.env` file doesn't exist or `PORT` is not defined in the file, then `PORT` is not set and default port is used. Note that this script won't work in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to read the port from `.env` file is to use `dotenv-cli` package:

1. Install the package: `npm install dotenv-cli`
2. Use the following start script to read `PORT` env variable from `.env` and `.env.local` files (omit `-c` flag to only read `.env` file):

```
"start": "dotenv -c -- next start",
```

Answer (score 1):

For complete solution utilizing `.env` I ended up using custom start script:

```js
//server.js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
if(process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    dotenv.config( {
        path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
        override: true
    });
}

const cli = process.argv.length > 2 && process.argv[2] === 'dev'
    ? require('next/dist/cli/next-dev').nextDev
    : require('next/dist/cli/next-start').nextStart;

cli({
     '--port': process.env.PORT || 3000,
     '--hostname': process.env.HOSTNAME || '0.0.0.0',
     _: []
});
```

and then

```json
//package.json
{
   "scripts": {
      "dev": "node server.js dev",
      "start": "node server.js",
   }
}
```

To set port then in `.env`:

```
//.env
PORT=4000
```

Drawback of this solution is new dependency to `dotenv` in your project

Answer (score 0):

On windows I could not find a simple approach with `npm run start` and setting a port. My workaround setup is to use different scripts.

```
"dev": "next dev", -- for development
"start": "next start -p $PORT", -- for deployment
"next": "next start -p 3000", -- for local testing after build
```