# Why nextjs is not using the port defined in .env file?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Why we can't run a nextjs server at a port defined in `.env` file?

It works when using `PORT=3005 npm run dev`. But I need to set the port in `.env` file.

Here's my configurations.

`next.config.js`

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    PORT: 3005,
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    PORT: 3005,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

`.env.local` file:

```
PORT=3005
NEXT_PUBLIC_PORT=3005 # test
```

Run in dev:

```
npm run dev

> myapp@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 13.5.6
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000 <---- It still try the port 3000.
```

Comment: Have a look to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804091/using-env-file-to-specify-server-listening-port-of-the-next-js-server